# How to properly add new items to a collection?

Tags: c#, collections

Here I am trying to store loads of datapoints of the custom WindDataPoint type.

However, I recently found out that the whole time, my code has been creating tens of thousands of duplicate data points. The data points change to the latest value, yes, but instead of adding a new datapoint, it sets ALL datapoints to that value as well.

Here is the code of concern:

```
    private void Timer_Data_Tick(object sender)
    {
        if (!Timer_Data_Enabled)
            return;
        for (int i = 0; (itsDAQ.getStreamCount() > 0) && (i < 6); i++)
        {
            WindDAQ.WindDataPoint thisDataPoint = new      WindDAQ.WindDataPoint();
            thisDataPoint = itsDAQ.getValue(Recording);
            dataPointCollection.Add(thisDataPoint);
            newChartPoint = true;
        }

    }
```

Here is the code for getValue() and getValue(bool record)

```
    //Get Real-world values
    public WindDataPoint getValue()
    {
        holdDequeueValue = DAQStream.Dequeue();
        holdWindDataPoint.Lift = Lift_Sensor.getForce(holdDequeueValue[ChannelOutOrder[0]]);
        holdWindDataPoint.Drag = Drag_Sensor.getForce(holdDequeueValue[ChannelOutOrder[1]]);
        holdWindDataPoint.Velocity = Pitot_Sensor.getVelocity(holdDequeueValue[ChannelOutOrder[2]]);
        holdWindDataPoint.isRecorded = false;

        //This translates the number of samples since start into actual time since start
        //Why not get current time? I don't want the current time. I want the time the sample was taken.
        holdWindDataPoint.Time = SamplesToTime(SamplesReadSinceStart); 
        SamplesReadSinceStart++;
        return holdWindDataPoint;
    }

    //Get Read-world values and set whether the sample is recorded.
    public WindDataPoint getValue(bool record)
    {
        getValue();
        holdWindDataPoint.isRecorded = record;
        return holdWindDataPoint;
    }
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Did you look at the result for `thisDataPoint = itsDAQ.getValue(Recording);`?

Comment: Yeah. I put a breakpoint right at the WindDAQ.WindDataPoint line, and watched what happens to the whole collection.

When the value updates, I can see the values change. But instead of creating a new point that has the new data, it creates a new point, and all the other datapoints go along with it.

So it will read, say, 16,000 for lift and add it as a data point. Then it will read 12,000, add a datapoint, and BOTH datapoints will be 12,000.

Then it reads 10,000 and then I have 3 datapoints that all say 10,000.

Comment: Add the code for `getValue`

Comment: Doesn't solve your problem, but it's pointless to have multiple assignments to the same variable right after each other. You could just write: `WindDAQ.WindDataPoint thisDataPoint = itsDAQ.getValue(Recording);`. In fact, you don't really need the variable at all - you could replace the first 3 lines of your `for` block with: `dataPointCollection.Add(itsDAQ.getValue(Recording));`

Comment: Nothing in your `for` block is incrementing the variable `i`. Is anything decrementing `itsDAQ.getStreamCount()`? Also, does `itsDAQ.getValue` return a *new* object, or does it return a *reference* to an object that gets updated values? That might explain why all the items in `dataPointCollection` refer to the same thing.

Comment: "dataPointCollection.Add(itsDAQ.getValue(Recording));"

That's exactly how I had it originally, so I'm glad that would suffice.

When I was working with plots, it wouldn't plot any new data unless I used the "new" operator for every additional point. I gave this a try to see if it would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You shouldn't be instantiating thisDataPoint if you're only going to redefine it after.
2. getValue is returning a reference to the same object every time.  This means that you will always see the same data.

Comment: How could you possibly know bullet 2 if you didn't see his code?

Comment: Actually, he has a point, though. I think I am passing an existing object instead of creating a new object and passing that. I'll have to check it out.

I didn't think about objects in a collection being stored by address rather than data content.

Edit: Yeah, I'm pretty sure this is what it is. How do you suggest I go about creating a new object and passing THAT?

Comment: Where are you defining `holdWindDataPoint`?  You probably need to instantiate it using `new` inside `getValue()`.  Also it would be useful if you could show your `itsDAQ` class definition.

Comment: @Yuval Itzchakov: It was an observation based on the information that was given.

OP: That depends on a few things.  Is it absolutely necessary to keep an instance of WindDataPoint in itsDAQ? If so, then you could always clone that instance. If not, you could make getValue return a new instance, using member variables stored there.  If you are only ever using 1 of the variables in WindDataPoint, just return that single value instead of the instance.